# how to update the fields from post method in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to update the field by clicking the submit from matdialog .

html

```
<h2>network <mat-icon (click)="openDialog(mytemplate)">add_circle_outline</mat-icon></h2>

<ng-template #mytemplate>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput placeholder="enter the items" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-stroked-button mat-dialog-close color="accent">CANCEL</button>
      <button mat-flat-button color="accent" (click)="onclick()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

.ts

```
provider = [];
  

     providers: provider;

getnetwork() {
    this.service.getAllNetworkProviders().subscribe(res => {
      this.provider = res.data;
      this.dataSource = this.provider;
    });
  }
    
        openDialog(template): void {
            // ask user to confirm, if he really wants to proceed
            this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(template);
            this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(isTrue => {
              if (isTrue) {
                const activatenetworkprovider = { networkName: this.providers.id };
                this.service.networkProviderStatus(activatenetworkprovider).subscribe(data => {
                  this.getnetwork();
                  this.snackBar.open('Successfully created new network provider  sim', 'Close', { duration: 2000 });
                });
              }
            });
          }
```

model.ts

```
export interface provider {
  id: number;
  name: string;

}
```

I'm getting error [ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
].

I have updated the questions .

Comment: Can you provide the entire .ts file please ? Are you sure that the providers property is defined ?

Comment: yes . @clanglai 


providers: provider;

Comment: That is the declaration, it needs to be initialized as well. Also, it is convention to start you classes/interfaces with a capital letter.

Comment: I have added interfaces  in the question . Could you please more specific ?

Comment: You haven't assigned any value to providers, you just have declared its type. You could do something like : `providers: provider = { id: 0, name: 'myProvider' }` to initialize it

Comment: @clanglai i applied your approach  . Its inserting but name is inserted as myprovider instead of user typing name

Comment: If you want `providers` to be an array of response provided by your user it's a very different topic and you should look at ressources provided by the Angular documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a declaration:

```js
providers: provider;
```

It is not an actual object/instance, but rather just a handle to an object. You still need to assign something to this with `=`. Preferably an object that contains a member `id` (e.g.: { id: 1, ... }).

It is also convention to name interfaces with capital letters, like this:

```js
export interface Provider {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: i have updated question .. still i m getting error

Comment: I would love to help you out, but I don't think we have enough information. Could you try to reproduce this in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) please? This way  we can easily help you find the problem.

Comment: I m new to this stackover flow  . i have tried to edit the question but it took me somewhere so i created new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644549/i-m-getting-error-undefined-reading-name-in-angular-how-to-read-the-data-fro . I gave enough information in this link .

Comment: A stackblitz would still be useful, as compiling with the eyes is really not that easy, especially when we are not used to the coding style. We would be able to test and change your code for you. Questions that include a Stackblitz get a lot more attention from the community and are generally more engaging to solve, so you will not regret creating an account.

Comment: okay i will create stackblitz